# Reg: Click event not working for dynamically added class

Tags: jquery

```
$('div.input-player-close#player').click(function (event) { 
    if ($(".input-player-close").length) {
        $('div#player').removeAttr('class').addClass('input-player-plus');
        $('div#player p').html("Select the filename");
    }
});      

$('div.input-player-plus#player').click(function (event) {  
    if ($("div.input-player-plus").length > 0) {
        $('div#player').removeAttr('class').addClass('input-player-close');
        $('div#player p').html("Print the filename");
    }
});
```

**What above should do**

```
<div class="input-player-plus" id="player">
  <p>Select the filename</p>
</div>
```

**After clicked**

```
<div class="input-player-close" id="player">
  <p>Print the filename</p>
</div>
```

The above fails to perform my expected output, looks no issue in the above code, still somewhere, something i am missing.

Comment: The title of the duplicate question is almost the same as yours. How did you miss it when you were searching before posting?

Comment: @barmar i tried this, no luck.

Comment: You must not have done it correctly. Update the question and show what you tried.